# LDAP search takes too long

Tags: python, ldap, ldap-query, python-ldap

I'm trying to get more than 50.000 records from LDAP (with python-ldap and page control tools).

I have searching filter, which is

```
(|(field=value_1) (field=value_2)...(field=value_50000)
```

But this request taking more than 15 minutes. I'm taking 10 attributes from LDAP for these records.

Could you please tell me if is it okay for some large request or I can try to change filter?

Comment: Unless you have an index on the `field` attribute, your query implies a linear search. Surely you don't really need to match on 50,000 distinct values? This is already a design smell.

Comment: It completely depends on which field you're searching on. It sounds like the field is not indexed. If it was indexed, there would be no problem with your query. If you'd like more specific help, you will have to tell us which LDAP server you are using (OpenLDAP, Active Directory, etc.) and which field you are searching on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refine your search base, and make it the closet possible to what you are searching for, for example, instead of querying `dc=company,dc=com` use `ou=people,dc=company,dc=com`.

You can also build an index of the field you are searching for, and you can also enable cache for your ldap, and finnally concerning your search filter, if you query the same attribute you can try something like:

`&"(field>=MinValue)(field=<MaxValue)"`

It's way better the matching every single attribute.